# Comments not adding when submit button is pressed with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Practising PHP by creating a very simple page that has a picture and the user can comment on it. I pretty much have everything down except adding the comment to the table within the database. I have it so I get an alert when the comment either gets added to the table or it does not go through. As far as I can tell, the code looks good but I could be wrong.

Here is the PHP file with the config info

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$user = "user1";
$password = "";
$dbname = "comment_section";

//Create connection to database
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $user, $password, $dbname);

if(!conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "CREATE TABLE comment_list (
    id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nid VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    comments TEXT NOT NULL,
    date datetime NOT NULL
)";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Table comment_list created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

And here is my index file

```
<?php
include 'comments.php';

error_reporting(0);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['nid'];
    $comment = $_POST['comments'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO comment_list (nid, comments)
            VALUES ('$name', '$comment')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if ($result) {
        echo "<script>alert('Comment added')</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Comment not added')</script>";
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title></title>
 

    <!-- CSS, JS, and PHP files goes here -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!-- javascript code goes here -->

    <!-- end of js code -->

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Intro to what the site is about, possible pages to include comments -->

    <header>
        <h1></h1>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </header>

    <!-- Image with comment section -->
    <article>

        <img src="images/IMG_1560.JPG" alt="" ">

        <div class="wrapper">
            <form action="" method="POST" class="form">
                <div class="name">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nid" id="nid" placeholder="Name" required>
                </div> <!-- End div class name -->
                <div class="comment">
                    <label for="comment">Comment</label>
                    <textarea name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Comment" required></textarea>
                </div> <!-- End of div for textarea -->
                <div class="but">
                    <button name="submit" class="btn">Post Comment</button>
                </div>
            </form>   

            <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM comment_list";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            
            ?>
                <?php echo $row['nid']; ?>
                <p><?php echo $row['comments']; ?></p>
            <?php
                    }
                }
            ?>

        </div>

    </article>

    <footer>
        <p></p>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Now every time I try to test and click on the submit button. I get an alert and the Comment Not Added pops up. Am I missing something? I also want it to show under the form whenever a user has left a comment. I know I can use Ajax without having to refresh the page, but I at least want to get the comment into the db/table and displayed under the form.

Comment: You are exposing yourself to SQL injection. First correct your code using bind variables and prepared statement.

Comment: There are easy ways to display any php or mysql errors - look into that. It's alot faster and easier than us guessing

Comment: @kinglish just try displaying errors, but did not give me any. As far as I can tell, the code is going through find just not posting.

Comment: If `date` isn't null, then what is it?